# Why cv2.line () can not take float values?

Tags: python, opencv

I selected two objects based on their color and i create a rectangle around my selected object.Now i have to connect them with a line, that's why i use cv2.line(). before that i create boundingRect().This rectangle is fine.after that i put cv2.line(img, (cx1, cy1), (cx2, cy2), (255, 0, 0), 3,4) for creat a line between them.
But the problem is whenever camera see my objects it gives me an error that  "cv2.line(img, (cx1, cy1), (cx2, cy2), (255, 0, 0), 3,4)
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
[ WARN:0] terminating async callback"

How can i solve this problme?

```
cv2.line(img, (cx1, cy1), (cx2, cy2), (255, 0, 0), 3,4)
```

TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
[ WARN:0] terminating async callback

Comment: Cx1,cy1, cx2,cy2 need to be converted to int .

Comment: To answer the question, because it takes pixel location as input.

Answer (score 2):

`cv2.line(img, (int(cx1), int(cy1)), (int(cx2), int(cy2)), (255, 0, 0), 3,4)`

The coordinates, x and y should be integers. You can convert them into int as in the above line.